# How to get the number of available seats

Tags: sql, count

Here is the table:
Flight (FlightID, MaxCapacity)
FlightBooking (BookingID, FlightID, NumSeats, Status) with the status :Reserved, Held, Expired, Cancalled.

I have already known how to display the Reserved and Held Seats but I'm having trouble with calculating the available seats which should be equal to MaxCapacity minus Reserved and Held Seats.

Any suggest for this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f.MaxCapacity - COUNT(b.Status)
FROM Flight f
INNER JOIN FlightBooking b
ON f.FlightID = b.FlightID
WHERE b.Status IN ('Reserved','Held')
GROUP BY f.FlightID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select flightid, 
       max(f.maxcapacity) - count(case when fb.status in ('reserved', 'held') 
                                       then 1 
                                       else 0 
                                  end)
from flight f
left outer join flightbooking fb on fb.flightid = f.flightid
group by f.flightid
```